# Check website for IIS6 compatibility

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, iis-6

I have IIS 7.5 installed on my local machine. I have developed an asp.net mvc 4  site, hosted it and it's working fine. However my client has IIS6 installed on their server. How can I test whether the site is compatible with IIS6.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Either install IIS6 on your machine or ask client to provide access to the server. You may also wants to suggest your client to migrate to IIS 7.5.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to install IIS6 on windows 7 machine. i believe the version of IIS for a machine is dictated by the operating system and cannot be installed standalone.

Comment: You are right, IIS 6.0 can ONLY be installed on Windows 2003 server. IIS 5.0 onwards, IIS has been tied to the operating system. You may still be able to acheive it, check this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43132/How-to-Setup-IIS-6-0-on-Windows-7-to-Allow-Classic